# Factor Analysis in sklearn: Explained Variance

Tags: scikit-learn, factor-analysis

PCA in scikit-learn has an attribute called "explained_variance" which captures the variance explained by each component. I don't see a similar thing like this for FactorAnalysis in scikit-learn. How can I compute the variance explained by each component for Factor Analysis?

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you can do it :

First get the components matrix and the noise variance once you have performed factor analysis,let fa be your fitted model

```
m = fa.components_
n = fa.noise_variance_
```

Square this matrix

```
m1 = m**2
```

Compute the sum of each of the columns of m1

```
m2 = np.sum(m1,axis=1)
```

Now the %variance explained by the first factor will be

```
pvar1 = (100*m2[0])/np.sum(m2)
```

similarly, second factor

```
pvar2 = (100*m2[1])/np.sum(m2)
```

However, there is also a variance explained by the noise component, if you account for that in your variance explained you will need to compute

```
pvar1_with_noise = (100*m2[0])/(np.sum(m2)+np.sum(n))
pvar2_with_noise = (100*m2[1])/(np.sum(m2)+np.sum(n))
```

and so on. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is actually not working for me. The figures I get for "pvar1" etc. all add up to 100%, and the last factor always has the remainder.  Aren't they supposed to be sorted by the amount of variance explained, descending?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the usual nomenclature of FA/PCA, the `components_` output by scikit-learn may be referred to as *loadings* elsewhere. For example, the package FactorAnalyzer outputs `loadings_` which are equivalent, once you change the settings to match scikit-learn (i.e. set `rotation=None`, set `method='ml'`, and make sure your data is standardized when input into the scikit-learn function, as FactorAnalyzer standardizes the data internally).

Compared to the `components_` output of PCA from scikit-learn, which are unit-length eigenvectors, the FA ones are already scaled, so the explained variance can be extracted by summing the squares. Note that proportion of variance explained is expressed here in terms of the total variance of the original variables, not the variance of the factors, as in the answer from @Gaurav.

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import FactorAnalysis
k_fa = 3   # e.g.

fa_k = FactorAnalysis(n_components=k_fa).fit(X_in)

fa_loadings = fa_k.components_.T    # loadings

# variance explained
total_var = X_in.var(axis=0).sum()  # total variance of original variables,
                                    # equal to no. of vars if they are standardized

var_exp = np.sum(fa_loadings**2, axis=0)
prop_var_exp = var_exp/total_var
cum_prop_var_exp = np.cumsum(var_exp/total_var)

print(f"variance explained: {var_exp.round(2)}")
print(f"proportion of variance explained: {prop_var_exp.round(3)}")
print(f"cumulative proportion of variance explained: {cum_prop_var_exp.round(3)}")

# e.g. output:
#   variance explained: [3.51 0.73]
#   proportion of variance explained: [0.351 0.073]
#   cumulative proportion of variance explained: [0.351 0.425]
```

Comment: if I set the n_components = n_features of the dataset X_in, I would expect cum_prop_var_exp to be 100%, but only ever reaches close to high 90s

Comment: @P4L No, your expectation is not true. Even if you set the n_components = n_features, there may still be some variance explained by private noise component. cum_prop_var_exp only captures shared variance even if n_components = n_features.